# airflow initdb in directory other than AIRFLOW_HOME?

Tags: database, docker, airflow, docker-volume

Question for Apache Airflow / Docker users.  I have a Docker airflow image I've built and I'm trying to use a simple SequentialExecutor / sqlite metadata database, but I'd like to persist the metadata database every time a new container is run.  I'd like to do this by mounting to a drive on the local machine, and having it so initdb initializes the database somewhere other than AIRFLOW_HOME.  Is this possible / configurable somehow or does anyone have a better solution?

Basically the desired state is:

```
AIRFLOW_HOME:  contains airflow.cfg, dags, scripts, logs whatever
some_other_dir:  airflow.db
```

I know this is possible with logs, so why not the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use docker-compose with a container as metadata database, like this:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8605#issuecomment-623182960

I use this approach, along with git branches and it works very well. The data persists unless you explicitly remove the containers with `make rm`